# CanWeMakeIt function python, it doesn´t return anything

Tags: python

I have to write a function that should return the bool value True if you can spell out myWord using only the letters in myLetters, and return the bool value False if it cannot.
To do this I need my letterPoints dictionary which is:

```
global letterPoints
letterPoints = {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 4, "G": 2, "H": 4, "I": 1, "J":8, "K": 5, "L": 1, "M": 3, "N": 1, "O": 1, "P": 3, "Q": 10, "R": 1, "S": 1, "T": 1, "U": 1, "V": 4, "W": 4, "X": 8, "Y": 4, "Z": 10}

def canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters):
    canMake = True
    letterPoints= list(myLetters)
    length=len(myWord)

    for i in range(length):
    i=i+1
    letter=myWord[i]
    if letter not in letterPoints:
        canMake = False
    else:
        letterPoints.remove(letter)
    return canMake
```

Comment: Not correct approach, you didn't call it , what to return

Comment: and how am i suposse to do it?

Comment: you can use only the value number of dict key letters?

Comment: There's no way this function doesn't return anything, did you actually _call_ it?

Comment: yes, i have to put for example: canWeMakeIt("cat", "tac") and it should return "True" or "False" depending on the letters.

Comment: @hackintosjdn Did you `print` the output?

Comment: what do you mean with "printing the output" I'm sorry man but i'm starting...

Comment: what @rawing is saying is that calling it in the current form is going to do nothing. You need to print your output to the console after. so basically, `print canWeMakeIt("cat", "tac") `.

But, what is the use of the dictionary. You are only using the dictionary keys, might as well have used just a list

Comment: I get "syntax error" and calling it like: canWeMakeIt("cat", "tac"), it says that there is an error in: letter=myWord[i]

Comment: @hackintosjdn: Remove the line `i=i+1` and use `print` with parentheses: `print(canWeMakeIt('cat','tac'))`.

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't doing anything. Nothing is indented into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function

```
def canWeMakeIt(my_word, letters):
   allowed = list(letters):
   for i in my_word:
       if i not in allowed:
           return False
    return True

#NOTICE HOW YOU MUST CALL IT TO DO SOMETHING
print(canWeMakeIt("cat","tack"))
```

Now let's analize your code :

- Your indentation is not correct
- You don't have to increase i in for loop
- You don't need to use dict if you don't know how, and it's unnecessary

Basicly it's work like this:

```
def canWeMakeIt(myWord, myLetters):
    canMake = True
    letterPoints = list(myLetters)
    length = len(myWord)
    for i in range(length):
        letter = myWord[i]
        if letter not in letterPoints:
            canMake = False
    return canMake

print(canWeMakeIt("cat","tac"))
```

You notice the difference ;)

Comment: See what happens if you try `canWeMakeIt("cat", "TAC")`

Comment: @Tonechas currently it's case sensitive ? that's the point I think

Comment: i dont know why when i put: canWeMakeIt("food", "afdor") it returns True instead of False. Where is the error?

Comment: the error is that in the allowed secton you have all three characters `f,o,d` doo word foor can be made

Answer (score 0):

You could count the letters in `word` through a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then compare those letters and the number of occurrences to the keys and values of the dictionary `available_letters` you pass to the function:

```
from collections import Counter

def can_we_make_it(word, available_letters):
    letter_counter = Counter(word.upper())
    for letter, count in letter_counter.items():
        if count > available_letters.get(letter, 0):
            return False
    return True
```

In the example you provided the keys of the dictionary passed to the function are in upper case. I'm making the same assumption here, i.e. the keys of `available_letters` are **capital letters**. It is important to note that as Python is case sensitive, it is necessary to convert `word` to upper case through `word.upper()` in order to avoid `KeyError`exceptions when `word` contains lower case letters.

It is also worth pointing out that you should check the condition `count > available_letters.get(letter, 0)` rather than `count > available_letters[letter]` to avoid a `KeyError` exception when `word` contains a letter that is not present in `available_letters`.

Demo:

```
In [275]: can_we_make_it('one', {'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'E': 1})
Out[275]: True

In [276]: can_we_make_it('Zone', {'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'E': 1})
Out[276]: False

In [277]: can_we_make_it('Zone', {'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'E': 1, 'Z': 1})
Out[277]: True

In [278]: can_we_make_it('ozone', {'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'E': 1, 'Z': 1})
Out[278]: False

In [279]: can_we_make_it('ozone', {'O': 2, 'N': 1, 'E': 1, 'Z': 1})
Out[279]: True
```

NOTE: I've taken the liberty to change the identifiers to make them more pythonic.